# Returning keys in a dictionary for every value in a list in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

So I have a JSON file which I have loaded into a dictionary. It has 8 different keys that it is storing information for. I am trying to create a search engine that returns the recipe that contains all the words in the search string and returns them. I change the string into a list of "tokens" that I will be used for searching.

Here is an example of some of the information stored in the dictionary. A recipe should be returned as long as the tokens are located in either the title, categories, ingredients or directions.

```
{
  "title": "101 \"Whaler\" Fish Sandwich ",
  "categories": [
   "Sandwich",
   "Cheese",
   "Dairy",
   "Fish",
   "Tomato",
   "Saut\u00e9",
   "Kid-Friendly",
   "Mayonnaise",
   "Cornmeal",
   "Lettuce",
   "Cookie"
  ],
  "ingredients": [
   "1 cup whole milk",
   "2 eggs",
   "1 1/2 cups flour",
   "1/4 cup yellow cornmeal",
   "2 tablespoons chopped parsley",
   "4 flounder fillets",
   "Salt and pepper to taste",
   "3 tablespoons canola oil",
   "4 sesame-seed hamburger buns",
   "4 leaves romaine lettuce",
   "1/2 tomato, sliced",
   "4 slices mild cheese, such as mild cheddar (optional)",
   "1/2 cup mayonnaise",
   "2 tablespoons pickle relish",
   "1 tablespoon lemon juice",
   "1 dash Tabasco sauce"
  ],
  "directions": [
   "1. In a medium-size bowl, whisk together the milk and eggs. In another medium-size bowl, mix together the flour, cornmeal, and parsley.",
   "2. Season the fish with the salt and pepper.",
   "3. Dredge the fish through the egg mixture, then coat it thoroughly with the flour mixture.",
   "4. In a large saut\u00e9 pan, immediately heat the oil over medium-high heat. When it is hot but not smoking, add the fillets to the pan. Cook on one side until the batter is light golden brown, about 4 minutes. Carefully turn the fillets and cook for 2 to 3 minutes more. Using a slotted spatula, remove them from the pan and drain on paper towels.",
   "5. Meanwhile, whisk together the tartar-sauce ingredients (if using).",
   "6. Slice the buns and spread the tartar sauce (if using) on the insides. Place a fillet on each bottom bun, then top with the lettuce, tomato, and cheese, if desired."
  ],
  "rating": 4.375,
  "calories": 819.0,
  "protein": 35.0,
  "fat": 42.0
 },
```

How would I be able to return the key in the dictionary that contains all the tokens in the string?

For example if there was a search string for "pancakes syrup" I would return the recipes on the dictionary that contain both "pancakes" and "syrup"?

This code creates a dictionary from the JSON file I am reading into Python:

```
file = open('recipes.json') 
recipes = json.load(file)
```

This code cleans the input string

```
def tokenisation(input_string):
    
    #functions to remove digits and punctuation and replace it with whitespace
    d_translate = str.maketrans(string.digits, ' '*len(string.digits))
    p_translate = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))
    
    #clean the string
    new_string = input_string.translate(d_translate)
    new_string = new_string.translate(p_translate)
    new_string = new_string.lower()
    
    #split the string
    splitted_string = new_string.split(" ")
    
    #make a list to store tokens in
    tokens = []
    
    #checking length of token
    for token in splitted_string:
        if len(token) > 3:
            tokens.append(token)
    
    return tokens
```

Then the actual search function (so far) is this:

```
def search(query, ordering = 'normal', count = 10):
    

    token_list = tokenisation(query)    
    values = [recipes[k] for k in token_list]
```

But of course it's checking each token on it's own rather than the all the tokens being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```py
def search(query, ordering = 'normal', count = 10):
    token_list = tokenisation(query)

    matching_recipes = []
    for recipe in recipes:
        recipe_tokens = []
        for key in recipe:
            if type(recipe[key]) != list:
                continue
            if type(recipe[key]) == str:
                recipe_tokens.append(recipe[key])
            for sentence in recipe[key]:
                # Make sure all the words from the recipes are in one big list
                recipe_tokens.extend([t for t in sentence.split()])

        if all([tl in recipe_tokens for tl in token_list]):
            # check if all the tokens from token_list are in the tokens of the recipe
            matching_recipes.append(recipe)

    return matching_recipes
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this method but I end up getting a type error of  list indices must be integers or slices, not dict when I try to populate ingredients.

Comment: Yes, I answered without knowing exactly the shape of recipes. Can you show us an example of input?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll add a picture to the question to show what is in "1 recipe" in the dictionary.

Comment: It's preferable if you paste some code / json instead of a picture. Otherwise, I won't be able to copy/paste it

Comment: My apologies, I've now shown an example of a recipe being stored in the dictionary.

Comment: I've updated (supposing recipes are a list of dict like you provided) :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it's much appreciated. I definitely understand what the code is doing. Would you mind explaining what the recipe[key].split() does. Isn't this trying to split a dictionary which cannot be possible?

Comment: I have made a mistake that I have fixed. Now `sentence.split()` makes sure that `"1 cup whole milk"` becomes `["1", "cup", "whole", "milk"]`

Comment: Ah I see what your mean now with putting it all into a list. However, with this example for the line *for sentence in recipe[key]:* I get a 'float object is not iterable error' and I'm not quite sure why?

Comment: Sorry again, I just added a test for the type of the key.

Comment: So after reviewing what this does, it does the right thing, however I also want to check for the title for occurences in the word, this code skips it because the title is not in a list. How would I account for this and change it so it works for that?

Comment: Check if `recipe[key]` is of type `str` and if yes, add it to the existing list.

Comment: I tried doing that but had no luck as it is trying to iterate through float types. I've tried to modify the code to this but it doesn't seem to work:


            for sentence in recipe[key]:
                
                if type(recipe[key]) == str:
                    recipe_tokens.append(t for t in tokenisation(sentence))
                
                #make a big list of tokens from the keys
                recipe_tokens.extend([t for t in tokenisation(sentence)])